# iOS - intercept outgoing SMS messages

Tags: ios, sms, jailbreak

is it possible to intercept outgoing SMS messages on a jailbroken iOS 6 device? What I want to do is reroute SMS messages via a free service, but still "reuse" the entire Messages.app UI.

I have seen some info about intercepting SMS on iOS, but they all talk about *incoming* messages, not *outgoing* messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to inject your code in MobileSMS application.

Now you can hook `-send:` method in `CKTranscriptController`. This method is called when you press "Send" button in MobileSMS. It's argument doesn't contain any information about message being sent so we need to find it manually:

1) Text and subject. `CKTranscriptController` has instance variable `CKMessageEntryView *_entryView`.

```
CKContentEntryView *contentEntryView = [_entryView entryField];
CKMessageStandaloneComposition *composition = [contentEntryView messageComposition];
NSString* subject = [composition subject];
NSString* text = [composition textString];
```

2) Recipients.  `CKTranscriptController` has instance variable `CKRecipientSelectionView *_recipientSelectionView`. It's `-recipients` method returns array of `MFComposeRecipient` objects. Call `MFComposeRecipient` instance method `-rawAddress` to get address string.

Most of the classes can be found in private `ChatKit.framework`. `MFComposeRecipient` located in private 'MessageUI.framework'.